# Why doesn't nerdctl cache a RUN npm ci layer, like docker does?

Tags: docker, npm, nerdctl

I have a Dockerfile that caches a `RUN npm ci` when executed locally with `docker` binary, but fails when running with `nerdctl`. Other layers are cached properly. Here's the relevant part of docker output:

```bash
[+] Building 1.8s (14/14) FINISHED                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.39kB                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring context: 112B                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-bullseye-slim                                                                      1.0s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-bullseye-slim@sha256:a6b88857a85c692ded74bee86c9d42630c646f8a77267c0a281fb726ae54cdba                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring context: 295.92kB                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [2/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales openssl curl ca-certificates gpg make --no-install-recommends   && localed  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/9] RUN curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-4.4.asc |   gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg   --dearmor   &  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/9] RUN apt-get install ibgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb -y         0.0s
 => CACHED [5/9] WORKDIR /opt/app                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [6/9] COPY package.json .                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [7/9] COPY package-lock.json .                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [8/9] RUN npm ci                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [9/9] COPY . .                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => exporting layers
```

All layers, even before this one, are cached. Nothing strange to see here.

And this is what I get remotely (running in a Jenkins agent in k8s) for approximately the same lines:

```
#7 [4/9] RUN apt-get install ibgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb -y
#7 CACHED

#8 [2/9] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales openssl curl ca-certificates gpg make --no-install-recommends   && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8   && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#8 CACHED

#9 [6/9] COPY package.json .
#9 CACHED

#10 [3/9] RUN curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-4.4.asc |   gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg   --dearmor   && echo "deb [ signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools mongodb-org-shell
#10 CACHED

#11 [7/9] COPY package-lock.json .
#11 CACHED

#12 [8/9] RUN npm ci
#12 21.07 
#12 21.07 added 212 packages, and audited 213 packages in 21s
#12 21.07 
#12 21.07 41 packages are looking for funding
#12 21.07   run `npm fund` for details
#12 21.10 
#12 21.10 6 vulnerabilities (5 moderate, 1 critical)
#12 21.10 
#12 21.10 To address issues that do not require attention, run:
#12 21.10   npm audit fix
#12 21.10 
#12 21.10 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
#12 21.10   npm audit fix --force
#12 21.10 
#12 21.10 Run `npm audit` for details.
#12 21.10 npm notice 
#12 21.10 npm notice New patch version of npm available! 10.2.3 -> 10.2.5
#12 21.10 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.5>
#12 21.10 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.5` to update!
#12 21.10 npm notice 
#12 DONE 24.7s
```

As you can see, the layer is not cached. The previous RUN layer, the one running `apt-get` is cached properly. The COPY layers are all good. I do not understand why then is the `RUN npm ci` a problem for Nerdctl.

Here's the Dockerfile producing all this:

```
FROM node:18-bullseye-slim

## Update system and install deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales openssl curl ca-certificates gpg make --no-install-recommends \ 
  && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8 \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

## Install Mongo shell
RUN curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-4.4.asc | \
  gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg \
  --dearmor \
  && echo "deb [ signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-4.4.gpg ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/4.4 main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y mongodb-org-tools mongodb-org-shell

## Cypress dependencies
RUN apt-get install ibgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnotify-dev libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 libxtst6 xauth xvfb -y

## Get e2e app set up
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm ci 
COPY . .

## Environment setup
## Redacted a few env variables here, but this is already past the RUN layer in question.

## Electron is finicky
ENV ELECTRON_EXTRA_LAUNCH_ARGS='--disable-gpu'
ENV TERM=linux

## Finally, execute the make all
CMD ["npm", "run", "run:ci:short"]
```